# is it right to use `if a!=0and b`? Note there is no space after `a!=0` `and`

Tags: python-2.7

Say for example,

```
>>> a=5
>>> b=10
>>> if a!=0 and b:print 'Hello'
Hello
```

The above snippet works fine on python console in every other os and online interpreters.!

Now on removing the space after `a!=0` and logical `and`, on python console in Mac or in any other online interpreters for python like TIO.

```
>>> a=5
>>> b=10
>>> if a!=0and b:print 'Hello' # note the difference
Hello
```

PFB the screenshot!
[image]

But the same doesn't seem to work on a python console in linux and windows and also in IDE like Eclipse with pydev plugin installed(Mars)

It'd be great if anyone could

- throw light on this behaviour!
- is it really pythonic to use the second snippet?

Note: realised this while working on few challenges in code golf-PPCG where the space really matters!

P.S. please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: I'll be damned! This _does_ work in macos python. I'm curious, how python tokenizes this code and why does it do it differently on other platforms.

Comment: If your second question is "should I use it in production code?", the answer is, of course, ABSOLUTELY NOT. Only in code golfing. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. Yeah it does! I've added the screenshot and I have no clue too! wrt the second comment, no I didn't mean that. Is it really pythonic is what I wanted to ask. I've edited the question!

Comment: And it does work on FreeBSD. I smell libc-specifics. And no, this is absolutely not Pythonic.

Comment: FreeBSD. What is that? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran: FreeBSD is an OS.

Comment: it works on my linux mint. Variable names can't start with a digit so its not too surprising that it works.... except I'm surprised it doesn't work on all cpython implementations.

Comment: That *should* work on any Python implementation. I can't reproduce the failures you say you're seeing on my Linux machine.

Comment: @tdelaney - agreed!

Comment: From the docs [2.1.9. Whitespace between tokens](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens): _Whitespace is needed between two tokens only if their concatenation could otherwise be interpreted as a different token_

Answer (score 3):

If you're code golfing, go for it. It's terrible practice in normal code, but code golf throws out all standards of normal code quality anyway.

Python splits the `0` from the `and` in `if a!=0and b` much the same way as it splits the `!=` from the `0` or the `a` from the `!=`. The source code gets fed through a [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) that splits it into elements known as tokens. Python's tokens include such things as number literals (`12`, `1.2`, `1e4`, `0xabc`, etc.), names (`foo`, `eggs`, `steve`, etc.), keywords (`if`, `and`, `while`, etc.), and so on. When the tokenizer hits this point:

```
if a!=0and b
      ^
```

it sees that the longest valid token starting at the `0` is just `0` - it can't continue on and include the `a` or anything after that, because that doesn't fit any possible token format. Thus, it splits the `0` from the `and`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but the question is why does it work on Macos and not on windows.

Comment: just a moment. I'll add the screenshot!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran: I'm not seeing a screenshot yet. Did it turn out that it actually works on your Windows setup? Or are you just busy doing other things?

Comment: I'm currently working on Mac. Will share the screenshot once I get my windows laptop!